# Documentation generation for nullable types

Tags: c#, xml

There was a question about the generation of documentation by C# compiler.

Source code:

```
public class SomeClass {
    /// <summary>
    /// Do some work
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns cref="Nullable{Boolean}">
    /// Some stuff
    /// </returns>
    public bool? SomeMethod() {
       return false;
    }
}
```

Compiler generated XML documentation fragment for method SomeMethod:

```
<member name="...." >
 ....
  <returns cref="T:System.Nullable`1">SomeStuff</returns>
</member>
```

Is there any way to force it to produce

```
<member name="...." >
 ....
  <returns cref="T:System.Nullable{System.Boolean}">SomeStuff</returns>
</member>
```

instead.?

Comment: What about setting manually the return cref to :
`cref="T:System.Nullable{System.Boolean}">`
?

Comment: Oh, thanks! Thats works! But ReSharper generates- Cannto resolve symbol. But i think, that ReSharper problems

Comment: Well you can `#pragma warning disable` but it's not really eye candy!

Comment: Note that `<see cref="x"/>` is used to make a reference to an actual type. There is no actual type defined as `public struct Nullable<System.Boolean>`, hence the reference is wrong.

Comment: Ok, if this is not correct, then what do you suggest, Lasse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no.

There is no way to change how the .xml files are produced.

Instead you will have to change whatever it is that is processing those files to handle that syntax, or change the XML documentation.

The problem here is that `Nullable{Boolean}` is no different from `Nullable{T}` because the part between the brackets is not understood as a type, but as a generic type parameter. `T`, `Boolean`, `XYZ`, it's all the same thing.

You will either have to change the tool that reads this (and I don't know how you would do that), or write out your references differently:

```
/// <returns>
/// <see cref="Nullable{T}/> with <c>T</c> being <see cref="Boolean"/>.
/// </returns>
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this syntax:

```
/// <summary>
///   Returns the field's value cast into <see cref="int"/>?.
/// </summary>
/// ...
public int? GetNullableInt(string name, int? defaultValue = null)
```

This means that the type reference isn't 100% accurate, but the highlighting of the documentation's tooltip preview is equivalent to what the signature preview looks like (colored `int`, uncolored `?`).

Answer (score 1):

How about using

```
Nullable<bool>
```

Comment: If i comment something like: <returns cref="Nullable{bool}" - compiler generates <returns cref="!:Nullable<bool>"> - its error

Comment: `public Nullable<bool> SomeMethod() {}` insted of `public bool? SomeMethod() {}`

Comment: changes in code not affect documentation generation in this case